# Run a .sh file depending on the content of a file

Tags: bash, postgresql

I want to create a .sh file that needs to have a look into the content of a different file, in this case is the postgresql configuration file.

Is there any way that I can run a command within the .sh file depending on the content of a different file?

Answer (score 2):

sure you can do it, in your script you can grep for some unique keyword from the content of file, if the content exists then ok else exit.

```
grep -F "$word1" "$filename"
```

If output success then the script run else not

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in the same folder `yes_or_no`

```
nano yes_or_no
```

with the content below

```
#!/bin/bash
search_for="foo"
grep -q "$search_for" "$1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "The file \"$1\" contains \"$search_for\""
    ./give_a_yes
else
    echo "The file \"$1\" doesn't contains \"$search_for\""
fi
```

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x yes_or_no
```

---

Create a new file in the same folder `give_a_yes`

```
nano give_a_yes
```

with the content below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\"$0\" executed"
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x give_a_yes
```

---

Create some data files:

```
echo "foo" > foo
echo "bar" > bar
```

---

Start the script

```
$ ./yes_or_no bar
The file "bar" doesn't contains "foo"

$ ./yes_or_no foo
The file "foo" contains "foo"
"./give_a_yes" executed
```